# Jquery to auto submit form, after receive value from ajax

Tags: jquery

I am trying here give `value = 1` to input and submit manually.

Then each time jquery get value from ajax response `value+1` and resubmit it. And make a loop to 1000.
With this code I successfully get new value to input but failed to submit automatically.

HTML

```
<input type="number" name="imdo" id="name" value=""/>
<input type="submit" id="submit"/>
<div class="output"></div>
```

JS

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$('#submit').on('click',function(event){
 event.preventDefault();
 $('#output').empty();
 var imdo=$("#name").val();
 var ajaxurl='admin-ajax;
$.ajax({
 url:ajaxurl,
 type:'post',
 dataType:'html',
data:{
 action:'wpse_2900_call',
 imdo:imdo,
},
success: function(result){
 $('#output').append(result);
 $('#name').val(result);
 $('#submit').submit(function(){return true;});
}
});
});
});
```

How can I submit automatically for 1000 time?

Comment: Submitting a request 1000 times is not a very good idea. It can potentially cause issues on the server side. You'd want to create a `for` loop or a `while` loop. Could you explain more about why you want to do this? Whats the end goal?

Comment: @Twisty 1000 time submit is just a to explain. If i will not defined any limit then code will Iterate infinity time.

Comment: @Twisty inserted value will be get from ajax, 1st i am unable to auto submit. 2nd i want to stop auto submit process according to manually submit value. Every time before auto submit value check for in start inserted value

Comment: I still do not understand the goal. Please provide an example of what data is returned. Your script suggest HTML yet then you talking about a increment limit from this returned value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `.trigger( "click" );`  as long result is < 1000 (untested):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $('#submit').on('click',function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#output').empty();
    var imdo=$("#name").val();
    var initialValue=$("#name").attr("data-initial");
    var ajaxurl='admin-ajax;
    $.ajax({
      url:ajaxurl,
      type:'post',
      dataType:'html',
      data:{
        action:'wpse_2900_call',
        imdo:imdo,
      },
      success: function(result){
        $('#output').append(result);
        $('#name').val(result);
        if (initialValue == '') {
          $("#name").attr("data-initial", imdo);
          initialValue = imdo;
        }
        var maxRuns = 1000 + parseInt(initialValue);
        if (result < maxRuns) {
          $('#submit').trigger("click");
        }
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Edit: You need to add `data-initial=""` to `#name`. Also you can test the code without `parseInt()` (still untested).

Comment: Thanks its working. Is this possible 1000 time submitting according to submit value?

Comment: suppose If I insert value 1110 then its go for 2110 ? or any other value

Comment: Yes of course. You just have to add up result and imdo before testing.

Answer (score 1):

**I strongly do not advise using this code.**

Here is an example based on what you suggested you wanted to do.

```js
var i = 0;
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('form').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#output').empty();
    var imdo = $("#name").val();
    var ajaxurl = 'admin-ajax';
    for (i; i < 1000; i++) {
      console.log(i + ": Call " + ajaxurl + ", " + imdo);
      $.ajax({
        url: ajaxurl,
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'html',
        data: {
          action: 'wpse_2900_call',
          imdo: imdo,
        },
        success: function(result) {
          console.log(i + ": Result", result);
          $('#output').append(result);
          $('#name').val(result);
          $('form').trigger("submit");
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="number" name="imdo" id="name" value="" />
  <input type="submit" id="submit" />
</form>
<div class="output"></div>
```

When the form is submitted (either by click or <kbd>Enter</kbd>) the form is submitted and it will process until `i` is 1000.

**Warning**

You may DOS your web server. Or you may make a recursive loop that causes the browser to lock up. Again, I do not advise using this code.

Comment: Am I missing something, or is this code infinite? At the end of each loop you trigger a new submit and start another loop.

Comment: It might end up looping in that way. Haven't tested it.

Comment: @KHansen addressed the code. No longer infinite possible.